# Mixed Content warning on Chrome due to iframe src

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, https, mixed-content

Somewhere in the code, over a secure site, the following snippet is used:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "pugpig://onPageReady");
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
iframe = null;
```

The iframe src attribute set here is actually triggering a callback but it's causing Chrome (version 54) to complain about "Mixed Content" as the src attribute is interpreted as a non-https url over an https:// domain and that version of Chrome is not presenting the users with an easy option to allow for mixed content to load anyway (e.g. shield icon in the address bar).

Changing the Chrome version / using a different browser / starting chrome with the --allow-running-insecure-content switch is not an option for certain reasons so my question is, is there a way to make the "pugpig://onPageReady" part be perceived as an https url?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

**Or**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="block-all-mixed-content" />
```

Paste it in `<head>...</head>` tags.

The HTTP `Content-Security-Policy` (CSP) `block-all-mixed-content` directive prevents loading any assets using HTTP when the page is loaded using HTTPS.

All mixed content resource requests are blocked, including both active and passive mixed content. This also applies to `<iframe>` documents, ensuring the entire page is mixed content free.

The `upgrade-insecure-requests` directive is evaluated before `block-all-mixed-content` and If the former is set, the latter is effectively a no-op. It is recommended to set one directive or the other – not both.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
` helped me when using the srcdoc attribute to sandbox external code snippets.
Those snippets loaded scripts that itself used protocol relative urls (just //someurl.com). 
srcdoc seems to be deemed insecure even when called from a https url

Comment: The first meta tag solved my problem (iframe with src targeting https but still mixed-content error in console).

Answer (score -1):

As log as i know, no, ther's not. If there is, it can be considered a security flaw, and it will be fixed.

[mixed content explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Comment: I'm aware of the mixed content security implications. As you can see in my question there are ways to bypass that and I'm not asking if what I'm trying to do is safe or not but for another possible way, given my additional requirements. Your answer doesn't add any value as this is a technical question, not an ethical quest.

Comment: What i mean is the both sides are linked. For security reason, the browser disallow (except for that switch) to do it. So if you can find a way to do it you will make useless the security block.If they allow to do that, is like leaving a security hole in the software. So you have to pass through https, or proxy it if the main resource is not over https.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but again, this is not a discussion about security flows as a whole or how software houses should protect their babies or the common user. It's a technical question and if you're not aware of a way to achieve what I'm asking then it's probably more useful to not provide a generic answer.
By the way, the URL under which my functionality lives is not publicly accessible and even the machines used to access this app only use a private and secure network. Not that it's still 100% but you get the idea I hope.

Comment: maybe i'm not able to explain myself. i will try for the last time.

is not a matter of tecnical way to do it. When they built that browser, they decide to block every way to mix secure and insecure content.
And when i say every way, i mean every way, and this is for security reason. So there is not a way, simply.

The link i posted is talking about passive and active content, so you can't even load images or CSS. Just imagine if you can load something like a script or so.

If i'm wrong, i will be glad to read other users posts.

Comment: I don't think you've understood my comments really.