# Nested Iframe doesn't have content after reload on Mozilla

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, mozilla

I have this problem on Mozilla (worked perfectly on Chrome) where the nested Iframe doesnt have content after reload (only empty header and body tag)

Somehow you can click on the search bar and enter (instead of reload) to open again and all iFrame will load as intended

---------Working Snippet---------

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-edison-9rwhwv?file=/index.html

Body index.html

```
<body>
    <div>Index</div>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var b = document.getElementById("iframe");
            b.setAttribute("src", "iframe.html?" + Math.random() * 100);
        })();
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
            console.log('I am the 1st one.');
        });
        window.addEventListener('unload', function (event) {
            alert('unLoad')
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

body iframe.html

```
<body>
    <header>
        IFRAME1
    </header>
    <iframe id="iframe2"></iframe>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var b = document.getElementById("iframe2");
            b.setAttribute("src", "iframe2.html?" + Math.random() * 100);
        })();
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
            console.log('frame 1 before unload.');
        });
        window.addEventListener('unload', function (event) {
            console.log('frame 1 unload.');
        });
        window.addEventListener('pagehide', (event) => {
            if (event.persisted === true) {
                console.log('This page *might* be entering the bfcache.');
            } else {
                console.log('This page will unload normally and be discarded.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Body iframe2.html

```
<body>
    <header id="h2">
        this is iframe 2
    </header>
    <script src="iframe2.js"></script>
</body>
```

I read something about bfcache, which is why i tried to put unload event to negate bfcache.

---

Found this thread with help from zer00ne about mixed content
[Mixed Content warning on Chrome due to iframe src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206827/mixed-content-warning-on-chrome-due-to-iframe-src)

But this seems to be a security issue to do

Comment: I had a [simular issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31529917/2813224)

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for your reply, have you solved yours? since my iframe doesnt have options to edit

Comment: It's actually the JS in the `<script>...</script>` within the child page was messy thus it was considered mixed content. Here's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236904/2813224)

Comment: looks like its because im trying to change the iframe source dynamically.

Comment: Changing the src of an iframe is usually as trivial as changing an anchor. In fact clicking an anchor can change an iframe src.

Comment: I found it! Thanks @zer00ne. Not sure if its still related with mixed content, but i run the function after 'load' event and it worked as expected!

Comment: That makes sense, iframes are one of the last things to load, `DOMContentLoaded` event on the `document` might also work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by calling the function after load event

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            function setIframe() {
                var b = document.getElementById("iframe");
                b.setAttribute("src", "iframe.html");
            }
            setIframe();
        })
```

Hope this helps anyone.